# debug assertion failed. C

Tags: c, file

trying to get the number of lines in a text file. and i get this error that i havent seen before.

the error says debug assertion failed. expression c>=-1 && c <=255

```
void get_lines(FILE* fp, int* plines){

    int i=0;

    char c;

    int number_of_conversions;

    number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);




    while (number_of_conversions != EOF && number_of_conversions != 0 ){


        number_of_conversions = fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);



        if (c == '\n' ){
            i++;
        }


    }
    *plines = i;


}
```

Comment: I think you are forgetting to iterate over the characters in the line.

Comment: it should be noted that a text file might end with 0 or more consecutive newlines. so if the last char is not a newline the line count can be 1 short.

Answer (score 2):

The code you presented does not correspond to the error message you presented.  The error message is related to an assertion somewhere else in your source code, having this form:

```
 assert(c>=-1 && c <=255);
```

The problem it signals is probably related to variable `c` in the scope where that assertion appears having a signed character type (`signed char`, or `char` on a system where default `char` is signed).  In all likelihood, the essentials of the code involved boil down to something like this:

```
char c = getc(fp);        /* DO NOT DO THIS */
assert(c>=-1 && c <=255);
```

That is a common error: `getc()` and `getchar()` return type `int` in order to be able to represent all possible values of type `unsigned char`, *and* -1.  If you assign the result to a variable of character type, then

1. You may invoke undefined behavior in the event that the result is outside the range representable by type `char` (e.g. 128 - 255 on a system having 8-bit, signed default `char`s)
2. If the program happens to behave consistently (on which you cannot rely unless the character type in question is unsigned), you lose the ability to distinguish an error condition from valid data.
3. If the target character type is signed, then although the result behavior is undefined for some inputs, a reasonably likely actual behavior would be for `c` to take values less than -1 in some cases.  In that event you could get an assertion failure.  ("could" because nothing is certain when UB is involved.)

To avoid those issues, make sure to assign function results to variables of appropriate type, and in particular, assign the results of `getc()` and `getchar()` to a signed integer type at least as wide as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is basically two things:

1) that a char cannot hold a negative int  (EOF is -1, I.E a negative int)

2) fscanf() stops when it hits white space and a '\n' is white space.

Suggest: using:

```
int char c;  
c = fgetc(fp);
```

an example program would be:

```
void get_lines(FILE* fp, int* plines){

    int i=0;
    int c = 0;

    while( EOF != (c = fgetc(fp) ) ) // returns EOF on end of file or error
    {
        if (c == '\n' )
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    *plines = i;
} // end function: get_lines
```

However, this still has a bug when the text file does not end in a newline

Comment: Hmmm. in the OP's code, `c` is never meant to hold anything except a char; the success of the operation is communicated via `fscanf`'s retur value. And the `%c` does not skip white space, unlike most other formats. Your answer also doesn't explain why there should be a failed assertion.